# Magwnto2 while importing products via CSV set qty to 'No manage stock'

Tags: magento2

I am importing products via CSV in magento2, but I want to import product qty as 'No manage stock' how can I achieve that.

Comment: in csv 'manage_stock' value be '0', so it will assume no stock management

Comment: Not working I tried